# Jackson inheritance instantiating superclass

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, jackson

I'm using jackson in spring boot to deserialize an incoming json.

The json can either be a user, student or supervisor.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "role", visible = false)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Student.class, name = "STUDENT"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Supervisor.class, name = "SUPERVISOR")
})
public class User{ .. }

public class Student extends User{ .. }

public class Supervisor extends User{ ..}
```

I managed to map incoming jsons to Students or Supervisors. But when posting a new user the user should be general and afterwards the backend uses regex matching on the mail address to determine whether it is a Student or Supervisor. So the incoming json is a User without specific Student or Supervisor properties.

Is it possible to instantiate User ?

I tried all annotations but none of them seems to do what I need it to.

Comment: Add a subtype of type User.

Comment: With this I get "Could not resolve subtype" exception because all subtypes match

Answer (score 0):

You can use defaultImpl and specify the superclass there. If the incoming JSON does not have a "role" field, Jackson will deserialize it as an instance of defaultImpl.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "role", visible = false, defaultImpl = User.class)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Student.class, name = "STUDENT"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Supervisor.class, name = "SUPERVISOR")
})
public class User{ .. }

public class Student extends User{ .. }

public class Supervisor extends User{ ..}
```